# Can't send mail to other mail-domain (only within same)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I can only send mail within same mail-domain, but not outside it. Am I missing something?

```
        try {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("noreply@company.com", "user@mail.com");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 25;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 10000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "smtp.company.com";
            mail.Subject = "Thanks...";
            mail.Body = "text...";
            client.Send(mail);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Error message when sending to other mail-domain:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The
>   server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
>   allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

I've no control over the smtp host, but I should be able to send to other mail-domain.

Comment: It could be a lot of things, but if the SMTP host does not have SMTP relay enabled it could cause this. There are several other things you can try that are discussed in other forums: https://forums.asp.net/t/966344.aspx?Mailbox+unavailable+The+server+response+was+5+7+1+Unable+to+relay+for+unixpeter+hotmail+com+
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156145/failed-to-send-message-to-emails
http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2006/04/05/using-localhost-as-mailserver-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-xxx/

Comment: You are using port 25 which is unencrypted and the server may not recognize port 25 any more.  Check with mail server website to see what option to use with Net Library.  If you are running from a corporate network that has outlook email the smtp port number may be blocked or require a proxy server.  Test code out on your home computer to see if it works.